# Version dependency error with setup.py but installs successfully with pip install

Tags: python, pip, setup.py, python-packaging

I have a project with the following directory structure:

```
- module_A
  - a.py
- module_B
  - b.py
requirements.txt
setup.py
```

The project has the dependency on standard python packages, and other git packages. They are listed in `requirements.txt`.

This projects is successfully installed when I install with pip.

```sh
pip install --process-dependency-links -e .
```

But when I try to install with the setup.py with the command

```sh
python setup.py install
```

It throws a processing dependencies error.

```sh
Installed /private/tmp/py2/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/aspect_based_sentiment_analysis-0.0.4-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for aspect-based-sentiment-analysis==0.0.4
error: pandas 0.17.1 is installed but pandas==0.23.4 is required by set(['PyAthena'])
```

Project [link](https://github.com/yardstick17/AspectBasedSentimentAnalysis)

As far as I understand, pip command is equivalent of `python setup.py install`. It would be great if someone can explain what is going behind the scene.

**Update**

pip does log the dependency mismatch warning

```sh
pyathena 0.2.1 has requirement pandas==0.23.4, but you'll have pandas 0.17.1 which is incompatible.
```

Is there any way package can be installed using `setup.py`?

Comment: Added the project link which has the same behaviour as described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `pip install` is not the equivalent of `python setup.py install`; they differ in multiple aspects.  One of the ways they differ is that `pip` can downgrade packages (uninstall and then reinstall a lower version) in order to meet a version requirement.  Under certain circumstances, `pip` is even fine with installing conflicting requirements; it'll print out an error message in red, but the command will still exit with status 0.  Inspecting the output from `pip install` should tell you exactly what is going on.